# vagrant up hangs at booting VM

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

This is the first time I'm running vagrant since upgrading to OS X 10.10 (Beta), so it may be connected right there. the `--version` is 1.4.3, VirtualBox is at 4.3.0 and when run with `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG`, I get the mess at the bottom. The `Vagrantfile` could not be more simple:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-14.04"

end
```

I get stuck here with the output below:

```
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "modifyvm", "76ef7d0b-2b19-4b12-9a1a-b5e0654a143f", "--natpf1", "ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SetHostname:0x00000100a219c0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::SaneDefaults:0x00000100a21998>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "storagectl", "76ef7d0b-2b19-4b12-9a1a-b5e0654a143f", "--name", "SATA Controller", "--hostiocache", "on"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "modifyvm", "76ef7d0b-2b19-4b12-9a1a-b5e0654a143f", "--rtcuseutc", "on"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO sanedefaults: Automatically figuring out whether to enable/disable NAT DNS proxy...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "modifyvm", "76ef7d0b-2b19-4b12-9a1a-b5e0654a143f", "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::Customize:0x00000100a53dd0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::Boot:0x00000100a53da8>
 INFO interface: info: Booting VM...
[default] Booting VM...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "startvm", "76ef7d0b-2b19-4b12-9a1a-b5e0654a143f", "--type", "headless"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
```

What's at play here? Version compatibility issues or something else?

Comment: Also FYI: I checked the vagrant status and see the VM's state as `poweroff` & `vagrant ssh` errors out. So it's definitely not `up`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After no response here, I posted on Twitter. A friend of mine pointed out the VirtualBox version could be the cause.

Updates in VirtualBox was not updating, so I:

- Used [AppCleaner](http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac) to remove the old version
- Downloaded the latest [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox-mac.en.softonic.com)
- Re-ran `vagrant up` without error

FYI to others that expect VirtualBox to update as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant showed the same behaviour today for me. However, a simple reboot of OSX fixed the issue. Maybe something to try before reinstalling VirtualBox.

Cheers

Jens

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this didn't help.